# Get data from table count in intervals of 5 minutes in last 1 hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the MYSQL default Timestamp value.

I want to get the count of data grouped by intervals of 5 minutes for the last 1 hour precisely such that I get
[24,65,85,12,32,45,68]

24 are the number of records that were created in the last 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have data for each 5 minute period, you can use aggregation:

```
select floor(timestampdiff(minute, timestamp, now()) / 5) * 5 as mins,
       count(*)
from t
where t.timestamp >= now() - interval 1 hour
group by mins;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, That's exactly what i was looking for.